# QlikSense connection to localhost application using REST

Tags: qliksense

Trying to establish a data connection using REST from QlikCloud account to a locally running application. I get an errror:

> Connection to local resources is not allowed

The application running on my laptop is having a REST API enabled.

I was not able to use QlikSense Desktop so I had to login through the browser to QlikCloud.

I also tried giving the ipaddress of my laptop instead of `localhost`. It still throws as error:

> Connection to http://<ip_address>:1000/v1/documents?uri=/csv/myFile.csv is not allowed

Should I be running my application only on a server? Any help is appreciated.

[image: Qlik REST configuration]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data connections are "executed" in the context of the Qlik Engine. Which means that when specifying `localhost` the connection will try and load the data from the machine where the Engine is running. In Qlik Cloud case - this will be some machine in Qlik's cloud.

You can:

- use QS Desktop (you've mentioned that this is not working for you)
- host your service somewhere on the interned where the Engine can reach it
- use some service (like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com)) that can tunnel the local server to a public url which then access from Qlik

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful to know.
can we still use QS Desktop? It seems to connect me to QlikCloud when I sign in.